# 'invalid blocktype: HM_Deleteorder_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid' in /app/Mage.php:595

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, sales, grid

Because we've accidently delete a module, we cannot access the adminpage.

Fatal error: Call to a member function setSaveParametersInSession() on boolean in /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php on line 66

in the logfiles we can find:

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'invalid blocktype: HM_Deleteorder_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid' in /var/www/html/webshop/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Ongeldig blokty...')
#1 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('adminhtml/sales...', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(66): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/sales...', 'sales_order.gri...')
#3 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->_prepareLayout()
#4 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#5 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/sales...', 'sales_order.gri...')
#6 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/sales...', 'sales_order.gri...')
#7 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#8 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#9 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#10 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#11 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#12 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(59): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#13 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(94): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->_initAction()
#14 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->indexAction()
#15 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#16 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 /var/www/html/webshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#18 /var/www/html/webshop/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /var/www/html/webshop/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

we've tried to delete all folder with HM_deleteorder, but all is gone. Still we receive this error. 
Tried to reinstall, but cannot find the module in the marketplace.

Answer (score 3):

Usually this happens because the cached layout contains a reference to the old hm_ block.

Please delete the cache by either:
- deleting var/cache/ in your Magento root
- purging external caches (such as redis)
- run n98-magerun to purge the caches

This should help.